# Generic matrix in Java supporting arbitrary rotations in constant time

Tags: java, matrix

I have this generic "matrix" holding elements of arbitrary type. It supports any horizontal or vertical rotations (of any step size) in \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$. See what I have:

```
package net.coderodde.util;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 * This class implements a generic, fixed-sized matrix of generic elements. It 
 * supports any rotations in constant time.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Apr 5, 2016)
 */
public final class RotableMatrix<E> {

    private final Object[][] matrix;
    private final int width;
    private final int height;

    private int cursorX;
    private int cursorY;

    public RotableMatrix(int width, int height) {
        checkWidth(width);
        checkHeight(height);

        this.width  = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.matrix = new Object[height][width];
    }

    public void rotateUp() {
        rotateUp(1);
    }

    public void rotateRight() {
        rotateRight(1);
    }

    public void rotateDown() {
        rotateDown(1);
    }

    public void rotateLeft() {
        rotateLeft(1);
    }

    public void rotateUp(int steps) {
        if (steps < 0) {
            rotateDown(-steps);
            return;
        }

        cursorY = (cursorY + steps) % height;
    }

    public void rotateRight(int steps) {
        if (steps < 0) {
            rotateLeft(-steps);
            return;
        }

        cursorX = (cursorX - steps) % width;

        if (cursorX < 0) {
            cursorX += width;
        }
    }

    public void rotateDown(int steps) {
        if (steps < 0) {
            rotateUp(-steps);
            return;
        }

        cursorY = (cursorY - steps) % height;

        if (cursorY < 0) {
            cursorY += height;
        }
    }

    public void rotateLeft(int steps) {
        if (steps < 0) {
            rotateRight(-steps);
            return;
        }

        cursorX = (cursorX + steps) % width;
    }

    public E get(int x, int y) {
        checkXCoordinate(x);
        checkYCoordinate(y);
        return (E) matrix[(y + cursorY) % height][(x + cursorX) % width];
    }

    public void set(int x, int y, E element) {
        checkXCoordinate(x);
        checkYCoordinate(y);
        matrix[(y + cursorY) % height][(x + cursorX) % width] = element;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
                sb.append(get(x, y));

                if (x < width - 1) {
                    sb.append(" ");
                }
            }

            if (y < height - 1) {
                sb.append("\n");
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    private void checkWidth(int width) {
        checkIntegerIsNoLessThan(width, 
                                 1, 
                                 "The matrix width is too small (" + width + 
                                 "). Must be at least 1.");
    }

    private void checkHeight(int height) {
        checkIntegerIsNoLessThan(height,
                                 1,
                                 "The matrix height is too small (" + height +
                                 "). Must be at least 1.");
    }

    private void checkIntegerIsNoLessThan(int test,
                                          int lowerBound, 
                                          String errorMessage) {
        if (test < lowerBound) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(errorMessage);
        }
    }

    private void checkXCoordinate(int x) {
        if (x < 0) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                    "The x-coordinate is negative: " + x);
        }

        if (x >= width) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                    "The x-coordinate is too large: " + x + ". The width of " +
                    "this matrix is " + width);
        }
    }

    private void checkYCoordinate(int y) {
        if (y < 0) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                    "The y-coordinate is negative: " + y);
        }

        if (y >= height) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                    "The y-coordinate is too large: " + y + ". The height of " +
                    "this matrix is " + height);
        }
    }

    private static final class MyCanvas extends Canvas {

        private final RotableMatrix<Color> matrix;

        MyCanvas(RotableMatrix<Color> matrix) {
            this.matrix = matrix;
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(matrix.getWidth(), 
                                                matrix.getHeight()));
            this.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
                @Override
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                    switch (e.getKeyChar()) {
                        case 'w':
                        case 'W':
                            matrix.rotateUp(10);
                            repaint();
                            break;

                        case 'd':
                        case 'D':
                            matrix.rotateRight(10);
                            repaint();
                            break;

                        case 's':
                        case 'S':
                            matrix.rotateDown(10);
                            repaint();
                            break;

                        case 'a':
                        case 'A':
                            matrix.rotateLeft(10);
                            repaint();
                            break;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}

                @Override
                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void update(Graphics g) {
            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(matrix.getWidth(),
                                                    matrix.getHeight(),
                                                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

            for (int y = 0; y < matrix.getHeight(); ++y) {
                for (int x = 0; x < matrix.getWidth(); ++x) {
                    image.setRGB(x, y, matrix.get(x, y).getRGB());
                }
            }

            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            update(g);
        }
    }

    private static final int WIDTH  = 1000;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 1000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        RotableMatrix<Color> matrix = createColorMatrix(WIDTH, HEIGHT, random); 
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        MyCanvas canvas = new MyCanvas(matrix);

        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
        panel.add(canvas);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static RotableMatrix<Color> createColorMatrix(int width, 
                                                          int height,
                                                          Random random) {
        RotableMatrix<Color> matrix = new RotableMatrix<>(width, height);

        matrix.set(0, 0, createRandomColor(random));

        for (int y = 1; y < height; ++y) {
            matrix.set(0, y, createRandomColor(random, matrix.get(0, y - 1)));
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
            for (int x = 1; x < width; ++x) {
                Color previousColor = matrix.get(x - 1, y);
                matrix.set(x, y, createRandomColor(random, previousColor));
            }
        }

        return matrix;
    }

    private static Color createRandomColor(Random random) {
        return new Color(random.nextInt(256),
                         random.nextInt(256),
                         random.nextInt(256));
    }

    private static Color createRandomColor(Random random, Color previousColor) {
        int prevRed   = previousColor.getRed();
        int prevGreen = previousColor.getGreen();
        int prevBlue  = previousColor.getBlue();

        int nextRed   = prevRed   + random.nextInt(17) - 8;
        int nextGreen = prevGreen + random.nextInt(17) - 8;
        int nextBlue  = prevBlue  + random.nextInt(17) - 8;

        return new Color(filter(nextRed), filter(nextGreen), filter(nextBlue));
    }

    private static int filter(int a) {
        if (a < 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (a > 255) {
            return 255;
        }

        return a;
    }
}
```

The demonstration uses this matrix for efficient rotations of an image. As always, tell me anything that comes to mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a look at the way you handle negative rotations...

and you seem to just negate the value, and then pass it to its opposite function. Which is a pretty clever idea. Except that there is one case in which it doesn't work.

```
    System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    System.out.println(-Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    System.out.println(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    System.out.println(-Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

Gives the following output:

```
2147483647
-2147483647
-2147483648
-2147483648
```

Yeah, that's right - negating `MIN_VALUE` will do absolutely nothing!

And as a result, your code dies from `java.lang.StackOverflowError`.

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12535130/540837) for a detailed explanation as to WHY this problem occurs - the simplified explanation is that it overflows because `2147483648` cannot fit in an int and it overflows to the next value which is `-2147483648`.

Comment: As a remedy take `steps %= width/height`?

Comment: That could work.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I know what happens on the bit level. :^)

Comment: It's for the other people who read these questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

You do `repaint` in every case statement, put it out and stay DRY.

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    switch (e.getKeyChar()) {
        case 'w':
        case 'W':
            matrix.rotateUp(10);
            break;
        case 'd':
        case 'D':
            matrix.rotateRight(10);
            break;
        case 's':
        case 'S':
            matrix.rotateDown(10);
            break;
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
            matrix.rotateLeft(10);
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: That way I repaint on **every** key input, and I don't like having computation I can avoid.

Comment: @coderodde I added a default statement for something, didn't I?

Comment: Did not notice it.